# Is there a free application which can apply adobe Lens Correction Profile (.lcp) files?

Tags: post-processing, distortion, software-recommendation, open-source

Seeking a free and preferably open-source, ubuntu-compatible application that can apply Adobe .lcp files to remove barrel distortion. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package RawTherapee, since version 4.0.9, will use Adobe .lcp profiles. Please see: http://rawtherapee.com/blog/rawtherapee-4.0.9-released

> Support for Adobe LCP lens correction profiles

It is available in the Ubuntu repositories.